# Is it possible to use multiple encryption keys for the same attribute in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know Rails 7 supports custom keys for each attr:

```rb
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :summary, key_provider: ArticleKeyProvider.new
end
```

**If we imagine here that an article belongs_to a user, I would like to use a different key per-user. Is this possible?**

Comment: It's per class according to the guides. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html#model-specific-keys